# How to import node view count with Feeds and Statistics module?

Tags: 7, feeds

After enabling drupal 7.x core Statistics module, on the feeds node processor mapping page, I still cannot find any suitable target to map.

Answer (score 0):

This [isn't currently a feature of the feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2311941). You could write a module that implements [`hook_feeds_after_save()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21feeds%21feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_after_save/7) to create the needed database records.